# Assign variable for javascript value

Tags: javascript

I'm still a beginner in javascript. I copy this javascript code here

```
  function memo(pnt){
      var row = pnt.lng().toFixed(5);
      row += ", ";
      row += pnt.lat().toFixed(5);
      row += ", ";
      row += pnt.address;
      row += "\n";
      printOut.value += row;
    }
```

and turn I want to asign

```
var lang = pnt.lng().toFixed(5); 

var lat = pnt.lat().toFixed(5);

var add = pnt.address;
```

the `row` is incremented.

but I get it wrong. what is the correct arrangement for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pnt.lng().toFixed(5) = var lang`

This is wrong to start with.

If I've followed your question correctly, you'll want something like:

`var lang = pnt.lng().toFixed(5);`

to assign the value of `pnt.lng().toFixed(5)` to `lang`.

Comment: but it is incremented. doesn't that affect the values if I assigned it like `ar lang = pnt.lng().toFixed(5);`?

Answer (score 0):

The ## var ## keyword simply identifies a **new** variable.  You don't need to have it on re-assigning a variable.